# is it possible to create detail page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to create dynamic list with detail page in WordPress?

Comment: i mean,if i have to make list of staff, with little information like name and image in front page ,and whole description in detail page,is it possibble ?

Comment: Yes it is, possible: https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an accordion or toggle plugin if you're already using WordPress that would allow you to feature multiple staff members easily/organized without cluttering the whole page.